# How could Chinese users pay for an app in software center?

Tags: software-center, chinese

I am a Chinese user, and I want to buy the game braid, but I don't have paypal, any cheap and safe way to solve this?

Comment: If you can use "amazon payments" or "pay with google", you can purchase braid on the official website. Since the downloads are hosted at humble bundle you should be able activate the download in software center on the download page.

Comment: Does being Chinese have any bearing on what response should be given, is there some sort of restriction you need to explain to us to answer the question better.  Does it limit you in creating a PayPal account for instance?. If not, maybe you should consider editing the question accordingly so that it is useful for others

Comment: I am not meaning I got any special rights when I say I am a Chinese,I just don't know if anyone from other countries faced the same problem. I have a credit card, and I will seek advise from the bank, thank you for you advice. But what I have to say is Apple had  accepted Chinese Yuan to buy apps, why can't ubuntu do some localization?

Answer (score 1):

[You can buy Braid from  [their official website](http://braid-game.com/) using **Amazon** or **Google** Payment method (and of course Paypal).  Maybe if you share what methods of payment are availble to you in the question stem we could help better.